# Is there a way to consolidate multiple rows of data in Microsoft Access?

Tags: ms-access-2016

I'm very new to Microsoft Access, and I'm trying to figure out how to output data from a table into a format that's more concise and easier to read.

I have transaction data throughout the year for specific customers. Based off of the Customer number and Catalog number, I would like to consolidate multiple instances of a customer purchasing the same product into one row, run a sum in the Quantity column for instances of the same product, and run a sum in the Price column for instances of the same product.

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2zGO.png)
[Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KuC2E.png)

I tried using an append Query with Customer # and Catalog # as the primary key to try to filter out duplicate entries, but this wasn't working. I'm not super familiar with writing functions in Access, but willing to try anything.

Comment: Sounds like you need to use the DISTINCT command to find only one instance of something to display when there are more than one of the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

An append query is used to add rows into a table. Is this what you're trying to do, or do you just want to display data from the existing table in a different way? Sounds like you just need a select query, grouping by the customer# and catalog# and then summing the quantity and price columns. Hit the 'Totals' button in query design to do this.